# Android Emulator Error In Linux

Tags: android, emulation

When I start My Emulator In Android Studio 
Started For Some Time Then Showing Shooting Down...

My Logs Looks Like This

```
4:58 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

4:58 PM Emulator: Couldn't statvfs() path: No such file or directory

4:58 PM Gradle build finished in 3 s 57 ms

4:58 PM Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

4:58 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can't Find Any Helpfull Pease Help.

My PC config :

```
Memory : 7.7 GiB
Processor : Intel® Core™ i5-3470T CPU @ 2.90GHz × 4 
Graphics : Intel® Ivybridge Desktop
GNOME : 3.28.2
OS Type : 64-bit
Disk : 176.2 GB
```